# git branch depulicated and overwrote common ancestor to make a linear history

Tags: git, version-control

I tried my hand in branches for git, and seemed to have flubbed it. Somehow  the topic branch is just part of the linear history of the master branch. I think it is easiest to explain by showing what `git log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%h -%Creset%d%Creset %s (%ct)'` returns.

---

This is what my current git log graph looks like, with `SHA-1 - (branch head) message (UNIX time)`. The message is just the order in which I had committed. There are three branches: master, hooks, debug.

```
* 7177766 - (master) feat: 9 (1473806908)
| * db62937 - (hooks) feat: 8 (1473803597)
| * b3e410e - feat: 7 (1473803486)
|/  
* ad358b5 - docs: 2 (1472707528)
* 63562a6 - feat: 1 (1472707509)
* c90dd7c - init: 0 (1472707503)
* 3570d3e - (debug) dbug: 6 (1472713561)
* 63eec96 - dbug: 5 (1472712406)
* 62ab5a6 - dbug: 4 (1472712076)
* 68a46ff - dbug: 3 (1472712076)
* 2936b65 - feat: 1 (1472712076)
* 16eaa61 - init: 0 (1472711864)
```

What I thought it would look like, and how I am visualizing the workflow in my head.

```
*    7177766 - (master) feat: 9 (1473806908)
| *  db62937 - (hooks) feat: 8 (1473803597)
| *  b3e410e - feat: 7 (1473803486)
|/  
*    ad358b5 - (origin/master) docs: 2 (1472707528)
|  * 3570d3e - (debug) dbug: 6 (1472713561)
|  * 63eec96 - dbug: 5 (1472712406)
|  * 62ab5a6 - dbug: 4 (1472712076)
|  * 68a46ff - dbug: 3 (1472712076)
| /
|/
*    63562a6 - feat: 1 (1472707509)
*    c90dd7c - init: 0 (1472707503)
```

The "true" first commit should be `init: 0 (1472707503)` SHA-1 `c90dd7c` (that which shows up in the master branch log), so SHA-1 `16eaa61` shouldn't exist (the first commit seen on the debug branch log). Alongside with the "true" second commit `feat: 1 (1472707509)` SHA-1 `63562a6` and not SHA-1 `2936b65`.

It looks like I somehow messed up creating the branch for debug. I should note that chronologically, the debug branch was made after already committing `docs: 2`. I'm not sure exactly what I did, but after committing `docs: 2` I probably `git checkout 63562a6` and made a debug branch from there.

---

In short, I am not sure how I got debug to make new `init: 0` and `feat: 1` commits, on top of put adding itself to the linear history. Does anyone know how I can fix this, and perhaps what mistake I made so that I might avoid it in the future?

**EDIT:** Looking through the reflog it looks like there is ample opportunity for me to have messed it up with a rebase. Still hunting down a solution.

```
ad358b5 HEAD@{52}: checkout:           moving from debug to master
3570d3e HEAD@{53}: commit    (amend):  dbug: 6
6a228cc HEAD@{54}: commit:             dbug: 6
63eec96 HEAD@{55}: commit    (amend):  dbug: 5
a5c79e6 HEAD@{56}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/debug
a5c79e6 HEAD@{57}: rebase -i (pick):   dbug: 5
62ab5a6 HEAD@{58}: rebase -i (pick):   dbug: 4
68a46ff HEAD@{59}: rebase -i (pick):   dbug: 3
2936b65 HEAD@{60}: rebase -i (pick):   feat: 1
16eaa61 HEAD@{61}: commit    (amend):  init: 0
477d2d0 HEAD@{62}: commit    (amend):  init: 0
00329f0 HEAD@{63}: commit    (amend):  init: C0
227c974 HEAD@{64}: rebase -i (edit):   init: 0
567c85f HEAD@{65}: rebase -i (edit):   init: 0
d901ba4 HEAD@{66}: rebase -i (start):  checkout d901ba4
95fc103 HEAD@{67}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/debug
95fc103 HEAD@{68}: rebase -i (pick):   dbug: 5
58b536b HEAD@{69}: rebase -i (pick):   dbug: 4
a285cf6 HEAD@{70}: rebase -i (pick):   dbug: 3
db852f6 HEAD@{71}: commit    (amend):  feat: 1
5001e98 HEAD@{72}: rebase -i (edit):   feat: 1
e29b722 HEAD@{73}: commit    (amend):  init: 0
6a99fad HEAD@{74}: rebase -i (edit):   init: 0
46ccd71 HEAD@{75}: rebase -i (edit):   init: 0
0584490 HEAD@{76}: rebase -i (start):  checkout 0584490
63af029 HEAD@{77}: commit:             dbug: 5
ca45966 HEAD@{78}: commit:             dbug: 4
11b3ca6 HEAD@{79}: commit:             dbug: 3
63562a6 HEAD@{80}: checkout:           moving from 63562a6 to debug
```

Comment: Have you looked at `git reflog` to see what happened to get into this state?

Comment: @alexbclay Thanks, didn't know about this command. I'm looking through it now and it's pretty messy...

Comment: @alexbclay I think I messed up between `HEAD@{76}`—`HEAD@{67}` on the debug branch when I `rebase -i (edit)` the `init: 0` and `feat: 1` commits. Then I further mess up `init: 0` with another rebase `HEAD@{66}`–`HEAD@{56}`. So I should be careful not to rebase edit common ancestry files? Is it even safe at all to `rebase` on branches? It seems that `feat: 1` gets a new SHA-1 at `HEAD@{60}` (compared to `HEAD@{71}` and I didn't even edit it, I picked it.

Comment: In general, it's dangerous to rewrite history using rebase too far back.  It's possible to get back your previous state by checking out the older HEAD hashes or references.  Looking at the graph from those might help you figure out your issue.  You can also add branches to those commits to see everything together.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see what exactly happened without being able to see your full repo.  Based on your reflog, I think you edited a commit during `rebase -i` which was then recommitted on top of the older one.

When you rebase, commits get new hashes because the datetime is used as part of the inputs to the hashing algorithm so it's hard to see the contents.  You can verify what's actually in the commit with `git show`.

To fix it, you can try rebasing again on the oldest common commit and picking the correct commits.  Before doing that, make sure to add a tag or branch so you can get back your initial state.  It's a risky process though, so be careful!